Solve equation with three square roots
I am trying to solve a more general question and I have the following subproblem:
Find $x>0$ that satisfies for fixed $ i \geq 3$,
$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{b^2}\right) x = \frac{\sum_i a_i^2} {b^2} + \frac{1}{b} \sum_i \sqrt{-a_i^2 + x + b^2x}.$$
I have tried commercial solvers (Mathematica) but they can't find a solution (they stop running after an hour or so). I have tried several transformations, for example using the identity $\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q} = \sqrt{p+q + \sqrt{4pq}}$ or taking squares of both sides, but the equation becomes more intractable.
Do you have any pointers or ideas?

For example, the solution to $x = \sqrt{3 + x} + \sqrt{2 + x} + \sqrt{1+x}$ is an algebraic integer of degree 8 (the unique positive solution is about 10.67), and I suspect that for sufficiently random integer constants your solution will be an algebraic number of degree $2^i$.  It doesn't seem reasonable to solve the equation exactly.  Are you having difficulty finding a numerical solution?

Are you sure this is the equation you are trying to solve? Note that when the $a_i$'s are non-zero and $x\rightarrow 0$, the right hand side is complex.

It's a step of a more general problem I'm trying to solve. I have done a lot of work to reduce the problem to this single equation. I need an explicit solution.
The original problem is here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/471075/nonlinear-system-of-equations-with-l2-norm?noredirect=1#comment1223956_471075
